# MySQL said #1064

Tags: enums, mysql-error-1064

I want to create a table with SQL code. It gives me always error. I've updated MySQL to maria Server, but still get the same error. Can you please help me what is wrong with the code

my code is:

```
CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `occupation` VARCHAR(45),
  `address` VARCHAR(255),
  `country` VARCHAR(45),
  `username` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `telefon` VARCHAR(15),
  `email` VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
  `password` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `first_name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `date_created` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `confirmed` INT NOT NULL,
  `date_modified` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `gender` ENUM(`male`,`female`) NOT NULL,
  `userType` ENUM(`member`,`admin`) NOT NULL DEFAULT `member`,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `username_UNIQUE` (`username` ASC),
  UNIQUE INDEX `email_UNIQUE` (`email` ASC),
  INDEX `login` (`email` ASC, `pass` ASC)
) ENGINE = InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8;
```

Result:

```
SQL query:


CREATE TABLE `users` (
  `id` INT UNSIGNED NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `occupation` VARCHAR(45),
  `address` VARCHAR(255),
  `country` VARCHAR(45),
  `username` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `telefon` VARCHAR(15),
  `email` VARCHAR(80) NOT NULL,
  `password` VARCHAR(255) NOT NULL,
  `first_name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `last_name` VARCHAR(45) NOT NULL,
  `date_created` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `confirmed` INT NOT NULL,
  `date_modified` TIMESTAMP NOT NULL DEFAULT CURRENT_TIMESTAMP ON UPDATE CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,
  `gender` ENUM(`male`,`female`) NOT NULL,
  `userType` ENUM(`member`,`admin`) NOT NULL DEFAULT `member`,
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  UNIQUE INDEX `username_UNIQUE` (`username` ASC),
  UNIQUE INDEX `email_UNIQUE` (`email` ASC),
  INDEX `login` (`email` ASC, `pass` ASC)
) ENGINE = InnoDB  DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8
MySQL said: Documentation

#1064 - You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MariaDB server version for the right syntax to use near '`male`,`female`) NOT NULL,
  `userType` ENUM(`member`,`admin`) NOT NULL DEFAULT' at line 15
```

Comment: What MySQL version are you using? Did you check the manual for that version to see if `ENUM` is supported?

Answer (score 0):

Enum's are allowed in MariaDb. Most probable reason is the quotes in the enum values. Change it to string like this:

```
`gender` ENUM('male','female') NOT NULL,
`userType` ENUM('member','admin') NOT NULL DEFAULT 'member',
```